# Vectorize a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I would like to write a function with the following signature

```
VectorXd vectorize (const MatrixXd&);
```

which returns the contents of a symmetric matrix in `VectorXd` form, without repeated elements. For example,

```
int n = 3;    // n may be much larger in practice.
MatrixXd sym(n, n);
sym << 9, 2, 3,
       2, 8, 4, 
       3, 4, 7;

std::cout << vectorize(sym) << std::endl;
```

should return:

```
9
2
3
8
4
7
```

The order of elements within `vec` is not important, provided it is systematic. What is important for my purposes is to return the data of `sym` without the repeated elements, because `sym` is always assumed to be symmetric. That is, I want to return the elements of the upper or lower triangular "view" of `sym` in `VectorXd` form.

I have naively implemented `vectorize` with nested `for` loops, but this function may be called very often within my program (over 1 million times). My question is thus: **what is the most computationally efficient way to write `vectorize`?** I was hoping to use Eigen's `triangularView`, but I do not see how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're going to need to use `TriangularView` and `Map`.

Comment: This feature-request is related: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=42 (see especially comment2 for an alternative way of packing -- you'd also have to do that more or less manually, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding efficiency, you could write a single for loop with column-wise (and thus vectorized) copies:

```
VectorXd res(mat.rows()*(mat.cols()+1)/2);
Index size = mat.rows();
Index offset = 0;
for(Index j=0; j<mat.cols(); ++j) {
    res.segment(offset,size) = mat.col(j).tail(size);
    offset += size;
    size--;
}
```

In practice, I expect that the compiler already fully vectorized your nested loop, and thus speed should be roughly the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited a small mistake: `size--` should come after `offset += size`.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are using `Index` instead of, say, `int`? I have not seen the `Index` class used before.

Comment: @tmnol `Eigen::Index` (by default) is just a typedef for `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is a 64bit integer on 64bit plattforms.